# Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x=1}^{n} \sum_{y=1}^{n} e(kxy/n) = \text{gcd}(k,n)$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x=1}^{n} \sum_{y=1}^{n} e(kxy/n) = \text{gcd}(k,n). 
$$

Here $e(\beta)=e^{2\pi i \beta}$.

Any tips how to start are welcome.

Comment: Let $\gcd(k,n)=d$, let $k'=k/d$, let $n'=n/d$, so $\gcd(k',n')=1$. Rewrite left side in terms of sums from 1 to $n'$. Now evaluate the exponential sums, maybe by separating out the term with $x=n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I can evaluate the sum if I can use your hint.. I got

$$
\frac{1}{n'd} \sum^{n'd}_{x=1} \sum^{n'd}_{y=1} e(k'xy/n')
$$
But cant figure how to make the sum index go to $n'$.

Comment: Split a sum from 1 to $n'd$ into $d$ sums, each containing $n'$ terms, then note that the summand is periodic with period $n'$.

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: Earth to Nklups, come in, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be too long for a comment. Start with Euler: $\exp(2i\pi\frac{kxy}{n})=\cos(2\pi\frac{kxy}{n})+i\sin(2\pi\frac{kxy}{n})$

Then, evaluate each sum: $\sum^{n}_{y=1}\sum^{n}_{x=1}\cos(2\pi\frac{kxy}{n})$, $\sum^{n}_{y=1}\sum^{n}_{x=1}\sin(2\pi\frac{kxy}{n})$, using the formula:

$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\cos(k\theta)=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\cos(k\theta)+\cos(n\theta)-1= \dfrac{\sin \left( \left(\dfrac{n}{2} \right) \theta \right) \cos \left( \left(\dfrac{n-1}{2}  \right)\theta\right)}{\sin \left( \dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)}+\cos(n\theta)-1$$

$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sin(k\theta)=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\sin(k\theta)+\sin(n\theta)= \dfrac{\sin \left( \left(\dfrac{n}{2} \right) \theta \right) \sin \left( \left(\dfrac{n-1}{2}  \right)\theta\right)}{\sin \left( \dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)}+\sin(n\theta)$$

Rather than this too messy and handy approach, I do believe there exists an approach using Fourier transform (and it will be much neater), but I can't find out for the moment.

Comment: Going to sines and cosines has to be harder than staying with exponentials. The sums with the exponentials in them are just sums of geometric progressions, so the formulas are much simpler than the trig formulas you are using.